# Jenkins Pipeline, use an Env Var within emailext plugin

Tags: jenkins

My Pipeline is generating a dynamic recipient list based on each Job execution.I'm trying to use that list which I set it as a Variable, to use in the 'To' section of the emailext plugin, the Problem is that the Content of the variable is not resolved once using the mailext part.

```
...
stage('Generate recipient List') {
    ...
    recipientList=`sort -u recipientList.txt`
    ...
    
}
...
post {
    success {
        emailext    
            to:     '$recipientList',
            from:   'jenkins@mycompany.com',
            attachmentsPattern: 'Projects2Shelve.txt,jobs2Delete.txt',
            subject: "Subject", 
            body:   "Hello, msg Body"
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a wild guess and suggest changing single quotes to double quotes might [fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/598141)